# Trouble assigning database parameters to values inside a for loop

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to make all non empty values in multiple textboxes to match up with the parameters in an insert query. The problem I am facing is that I am having repeated entries of the same value for each field in the database table I am using. I've investigated this on google and stack overflow and while a for loop is apparently recommended over a foreach, I cannot find a concrete answer to my question.

Here is my code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listOfTextboxes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

private void InsertData()
{

    using (dbConn)
    {
            dbConn.Open();

            using (var dbCmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO members (household_head, birthday, phone, email, address, status, spouse, spouse_phone, spouse_email, " +
              "anniversary, spouse_status, child1, child1_birthday, child1_email, " +
         "child2, child2_birthday, child2_email, child3, child3_birthday, child3_email, child4, child4_birthday, child4_email, child5, child5_birthday, child5_email," +
         "child6, child6_birthday, child6_email, child7, child7_birthday, child7_email) " +
         "VALUES (@household_head, @birthday, @phone, @email, @address, @status, @spouse, @spouse_phone, @spouse_email, @anniversary, @spouse_status," +
         "@child1, @child1_birthday, @child1_email, " +
         "@child2, @child2_birthday, @child2_email, @child3, @child3_birthday, @child3_email, @child4, @child4_birthday, @child4_email," +
         "@child5, @child5_birthday, @child5_email, @child6, @child6_birthday, @child6_email, @child7, @child7_birthday, @child7_email)", dbConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    InsertDBParameters(dbCmd);

                    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    return;
                }
            }


            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted.");
        }
    }

    private void InsertDBParameters(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        List<String> checkBoxes = new List<String>();

        foreach (Control cbox in Controls)
        {
            if (cbox is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)cbox).Checked)
            {
                checkBoxes.Add("Member");
            }
            else if (cbox is CheckBox && !((CheckBox)cbox).Checked)
            {
                checkBoxes.Add("Regular Attender");
            }
        }


        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text))
            {
                listOfTextboxes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(((TextBox)c).Name, ((TextBox)c).Text));
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < listOfTextboxes.Count; i++)
        {
            // loop through the list and assign each textbox field's not empty value
            // to the corresponding field in the database table members
            if (i == listOfTextboxes.Count - 1)
            {
                // last item
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@household_head", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            /*
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@household_head", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", checkBoxes[0]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spouse", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spouse_phone", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spouse_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anniversary", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spouse_status", checkBoxes[0]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child1", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child1_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child1_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child2", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child2_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child2_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child3", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child3_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child3_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child4_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child5_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child6", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child6_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child6_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child7", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child7_birthday", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@child7_email", listOfTextboxes[i]);
            */
        }
    }
```

and the invocation of the insert event itself:

```
 insertRecordsButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
 {
     InsertData();
 };
```

I have the exact parameters I would like to use in the `InsertDBParameters` method but I am unsure of how to avoid having the same value inserted for each column. I am sorry if this is a dumb question but I have been stuck on it for a day now and have no idea on how to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: With `listOfTextboxes[i]` You're assigning the same TextBox-value to each parameter in you're commented out part.

Comment: Yeah I know that I just don't know how to match up all the values filled out to the right columns

Comment: And how do you know which textbox belongs to which column? With the textbox name?

Comment: Yes, the names are unique.

Comment: Yes, the textbox name. I assigned a key value pair containing the name and text of the textboxes.

Comment: So your textboxes are named like `txt_household_head` or something like this?

Comment: Yeah, just each is a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the parameter-names in your SQL command to the names of the textboxes, if they are not already the same as the parameter names:

```
VALUES (@txt_household_head, @txt_birthday, @txt_phone, @txt_email, ...
```

and change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@household_head", listOfTextboxes[i]);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", listOfTextboxes[i].Key.ToString()), listOfTextboxes[i].Value);
```

And i would consider to use a `Dictionary` instead of `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: would I use:

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", listOfTextboxes[i].Key.ToString()), listOfTextboxes[i].Value);

and add more of these but change the String.Format first argument so it is {1}, etc etc, because right now it is throwing a exception that the number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

Comment: I have 31 textboxes on the windows form program I am currently developing.

Comment: No, you need just the one line from my answer. Read about how string.Format() works. You'll see the idea.

Comment: Then the number of TextBoxes and columns in your SQL-string are not the same. You say you have **31** TextBoxes but i count **32** columns in your SQL-string.

Comment: well one of them is a checkbox.

Comment: I added it so it is like this:

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfTextboxes.Count; i++)
           
 {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedCheckbox.Count; j++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", selectedCheckbox[j].Key.ToString()), selectedCheckbox[j].Value);
                }
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", listOfTextboxes[i].Key.ToString()), listOfTextboxes[i].Value);
            }

but I'm having the same issue :/

Comment: Now it runs the checkbox-loop for every textbox. Just run the two loops one after each other and it should work.

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception. I've looked over everything and can't see why it is saying this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152645/discussion-between-matsnow-and-user2101411).